# Merge 2 lists according to values in a boolean list

Tags: kdb

I have a method of achieving this which also explains my question.

```
a:1 2 3 4;
b:5 6 7;
cond:1101001b;
comb:(count cond) # 0N;
comb[where cond]:a;
comb[where not cond]:b
```

But q has so many utilities for manipulating lists, I am wondering if there is a more direct way of doing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`rank`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/rank/) is what you need.

```
q)comb
1 2 5 3 6 7 4
q)(b,a)rank cond
1 2 5 3 6 7 4
```

Comment: Elegant, this is more worth as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could write the expression in a single line

```
comb:@[;where not cond;:;b] @[;where cond;:;a] (count cond)#0N
```

Alternatively, assuming the 1s and 0s of cond matches the lengths of a and b:

```
(a,b) iasc where[cond],where not cond
```

Comment: I like the second option more than the first.